# Creating framework with Cocoapods 0.36 in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

Been stuck on this past 2 days
I am trying to create my own dynamic framework on iOS 8.3. I needed to use FMDB in my framework.
With Cocoapods 0.36 installed, I did a pod install on the following Podfile

```
use_frameworks!
target "PoddedFramework" do
    pod 'FMDB'
end
```

This works just fine and creates the required pod frameworks and workspace.
But, I can't find a way to use the FMDB pod in my own framework or my demo project that uses the framework.

```
#import <FMDB/FMDB.h>
```

This statement results in a "Could not build module 'FMDB'" build error in my own framework.
If I include the above statement in the public header of my framework and try to use that public header in my demo project, I get an error saying "File not found" for FMDB.h

I have seen a lot of questions regarding integration with swift, but could not find anything regarding objective-C

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with that framework a few weeks ago and it has been one of my headaches, but yesterday (Feb 6, 2018) after trying many things, I made the following adjustments taking another FMDB project as an example.

After installing FMDB (2.7.2) with `"pod install"` and opening the `.xcworkspace` I thought it would be fine and I could use it, but no, I found some differences mainly in the option Search Paths -> Header Search Paths as I show in the image [configuration pods Search Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdIoM.png) and [configuration FMDBtest Search Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuzvW.png).

Then link in my viewController.m with `#import "FMDB.h"`, if it does not work, try the option `#import <FMDB / FMDB.h>`